# cakephp PayPal IPN Integration

Tags: cakephp, paypal, integration, paypal-ipn

I am using CakePHP 1.3.10 version and want to integrate PayPal IPN for Payment Process.

I have found some ready made plug-ins though not working properly and returning bunch of errors.

I would like your suggestions, Any body in community using the same with success and any tutorial to integrate in easy steps.

Your response would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: when i enable PayPal IPN in my sandbox developer account, it says `IPN delivery failed. Unable to connect to the specified URL. Please verify the URL and try again.` Why?

Comment: have you set up the url to handle paypal request yet?

Comment: i am trying to set URL, but gives above error, when i keep any live website, it works, but whenever some IP like 202.. a live working IP from browser, is not accepted there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Paypal IPN with cake before, and it's simple enough to not have to reply on a plugin. Are you using that to track getting payment in a cake app? You can create the paypal form/button in your paypal account, set the url callback so paypal can notify you. Create a table in DB if you want to record the info paypal sends you. Have a method in the controller to handle the POST data from paypal. Here's my code example:

> ```
> function blah() {
>    $this->autoRender = false;
>    // post back to PayPal system to validate
>    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
>    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
>       $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
>       $req .= "&$key=$value";
>    }
>    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
>    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
>    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
>    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
>    if (!$fp) {// HTTP ERROR, we should record the data still..?
>    } else {
>       fputs($fp, $header . $req);
>       while (!feof($fp)) {
>          $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
>          if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {// verified from paypal, processing...
>          } else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
>             // oh no, someone is hijacking us...
>          }
>       }
>       fclose($fp);
>    }
> }
> ```

What fields to have in the table depends on what you want to keep. Look up the IPN API, and you can setup sandbox testing with paypal.

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered a nice PHP class, that runs all the PayPal IPN.

https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/

I turned it into a Component for my CakePhp project. 
For this just create a new Component in you app/Controller/Components/ folder and paste the code from that project.
Then Change:

```
class IpnListener {
...
```

to

```
class IpnListener extends Component {
...
```

Then go back to the controller you want to you PayPal Ipn with and add:

```
public $components = array('IpnListener');
```

You can than access the class using:

```
$this->IpnListener->foo
```

within your controller functions

Hope this helps